# Como modificar la cadena de conexion del webconfig desde el controlador

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo este conexionstring y quisiera desde el controlador cambiar el data source y demas parametros, como puedo hacer esto?? Gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes hacer eso, lo que si puedes hacer es definir varias cadenas de conexión y en tiempo de ejecución usar una u otra.

Comment: No puedes editar el contenido del archivo. Si la conexion pero no el archivo como tal.

Comment: mi problema es que la aplicacion se conectara a varias base de datos pero no se sabe hasta que el usuario se autentica, por eso no puedo definir varias cadenas de conexion, alguna solucion para esto ???

Comment: Claro que puedes, precisamente para eso está. En el config defines tantas cadenas de conexión a las diferentes bases de datos como necesites y en función del usuario que inicia sesión (u operación que vayas a hacer) utilizas una u otra. Es simplemente agregar más lineas <add name=...../>

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer eso. El fichero de configuración es un archivo no editable en tiempo de ejecución o compilación, utilizado para lo que su propio nombre define.

Lo que si puedes hacer es indicar varias cadenas de conexión y en tiempo de ejecución usar una u otra, precisamente para eso está el fichero de configuración (configuras diferentes cadenas para usar durante la ejecución).

En el `config` defines tantas cadenas de conexión a las diferentes bases de datos como necesites y en función del usuario que inicia sesión (u operación que vayas a hacer) utilizas una u otra. Es simplemente agregar más lineas `<add name=...../>`